# Puppeteer: content of frame cannot read property of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Мой тестовый html файл:

```
<div id="mainBlock">
    <div  class="underBlock">
        Hello!
    </div>
</div>
```

Я пытаюсь получить содержания блока "underBlock"

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless:false,
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    let response =  await page.goto('http://localhost/TestPup/Index.html');
    let block = await page.waitForXPath("//div[contains(@class,'underBlock')]")
    let frame = await block.contentFrame()
    console.log(frame.content())
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Но получаю следующую ошибку:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of null
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, [`elementHandle.contentFrame()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#elementhandlecontentframe) возвращает фрейм только для элементов `iframe`, а у вас обычный `div`, который содержится в основном фрейме, то есть в `page`, и внутри которого нет никаких фреймов.